# Getting "NameError: name not defined" when accessing previously defined variables

Tags: python, nameerror

I am receiving *NameError: name 'index1' is not defined* on the last **if** statement. I don't understand what is the problem since I defined index1 and index2 in the previous block of code.

```
...
else:
    for l1 in Xdisp_list:
        for l2 in l1:
            if l2 == from_previous[run_number-2]:
                index1 = (wn_final.index(l1))
                index2 = (wn_final[wn_final.index(l1)].index(l2))
            else:
                pass
    if w_ki - Xdisp_list[index1][index2] < delta:
        code_list_run.append(0)
...
```

To clarify the code:
*Xdisp_list* is a list of lists
*run_number* is an integer
*wn_final* is also a list of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you define index1 and index2 inside an if else statement, so if the statement
`l2 == from_previous[run_number-2]`
evaluates to `False` neither will have been defined when the line `w_ki - Xdisp_list[index1][index2] < delta` is evaluated,

you can either add the second if statement inside the first or define a default value of index1 and index2 like this, in which case the else statement is no longer needed

```
else:
    for l1 in Xdisp_list:
        for l2 in l1:
            if l2 == from_previous[run_number-2]:
                index1 = (wn_final.index(l1))
                index2 = (wn_final[wn_final.index(l1)].index(l2))

                if w_ki - Xdisp_list[index1][index2] < delta:
                    code_list_run.append(0)
```